# Find closest value in Binary Search Tree in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is my code. When I run my closestValue() method, I always get 0. Does anyone know how to get the closest value to an integer? This means I want the closest integer to the one I choose the closest value to but has to be present in the tree to be displayed

```
 template<typename T>
T bst<T>::closestValue(T value) const {

}

template<typename T>
T bst<T>::closestValue(T value, T & closest, bst_node<T>* node) const
{
    bst<T>* pClosest = NULL;
    int minDistance = 5000;

    bst<T>* pNode = root;

    while(pNode != NULL)
    {
        int distance = abs(pNode->value - value);
        if(distance < minDistance)
        {
            minDistance = distance;
            pClosest = pNode;
        }

        if(distance == 0)
            break;

        if(pNode->m_nValue > value)
            pNode = pNode->m_pLeft;
        else if(pNode->m_nValue < value)
            pNode = pNode->m_pRight;
    }

    return pClosest;
}
```

Comment: 1. Run it in a *debugger* with known-answer tests and find out why it doesn't behave as you suspect. 2. Post a [**minimal**, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the problem. Five hundred lines of code is certainly *not* minimal, and there is neither source data, or even a `main()`, so it isn't complete either.

Comment: I only left the closestValue method. my main driver is in another file and it contains no errors, I know that the error comes from here. I would post the main but it is way too long and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Is your single-argument `closestValue` function really completely *empty* ? As in.. No code *at all*? That in itself invokes undefined behavior, as you claim it turns a `T`, but in fact returns *nothing*. I can't believe that doesn't toss up at least a "Control reaches end of non-void function" warning.

Comment: In the 1st line in while loop, value is being called by pNode->value but in the if else it is called by pNode->m_nValue??

Comment: Hey guys I obviously made some mistakes and need help. Can someone tell me what the problem is and why am I not getting the right answer?