# Find the Closest Value in Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

- I want to find the closest value in a binary search tree taking an integer as parameter. The method closestValue() should return the integer in the tree with the smallest difference.
- The problem is that I run the application and closestValue always gives me a 0.
- I also have a control reaches end of non-void function in my constructor.
  Does anyone know how to fix this?

  ```
      template<typename T>
   T bst<T>::closestValue(T value) const
  {
  return T();
  }

  template<typename T>
  T bst<T>::closestValue(T value, T & closest, bst_node<T>* node) const
  {
  bst_node<T>* pClosest = NULL;
  int minDistance = 5000;

  bst_node<T>* pNode = root;

  while(pNode != NULL)
  {
      int distance = abs(pNode->value);
      if(distance < minDistance)
      {
          minDistance = distance;
          pClosest = pNode;
      }

      if(distance == 0)
          break;

      if(pNode->value > value)
          pNode = pNode->left;
      else if(pNode->value < value)
          pNode = pNode->right;
  }

  return pClosest;
   }
  ```

Comment: [*"It's like deja vu all over again"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729137/find-closest-value-in-binary-search-tree-in-c).

Comment: Are we supposed to comment quotes or try to help each other? Otherwise I have some pretty good quotes too

Comment: As I said in the duplicate post, your single parameter function doesn't *do* anything. I would naturally expect it to not work. The three parameter version doesn't actually use two of the parameters. And you have declared `pNode` and `pClosest` as `bst<T>*`, yet in your *real* code the `root` member of `bst<T>` is actually `bst_node<T>*`.  I guess simply don't understand what actually *works*. The algorithm in that proc seems sound but the types and various problems pointed out would certainly keep this from *compiling*, much less running to a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any suggestion to what I should do?

Comment: By the way it is not working and throwing a control reached end of non-void

Comment: That isn't in your constructor, it's in the original version of the single-parameter `closestValue` member you posted in your duplicate question. it was effectively empty. The function claims to return a `T`, but in fact, returned nothing. You "fixed" that error by just returning the input parameter in this post, but that certainly won't fix the original problem. I think you should rethink your choice of implementation. I see no need to have two members to do this. A single-param version should work. Also think about what you return when an *empty* tree is asked for closest-value of something.

Comment: yes, i have the empty tree exception in my main. I just edited the code following your advice but I still get 0. I edited the code on this page again.